# Перегрузка Object.prototype

Tags: javascript

Есть объект на странице:

```
<div id="obj" style="position:absolute;top:20px;">test</div>
```

Нужно перегрузить событие:

alert(document.getElementById('obj').style.top);

таким образом, чтобы алерт выдал, например 1000px

Дошел пока до этого:

```
Object.prototype.style = function() {
return Parent;
}
Object.prototype.style.top = '1000px';
document.getElementById = function() {
return this;
}
```

Но данная реализация перезаписывает getElementById, что совсем нехорошо.

Вопрос: как же это реализовать?

> UPD: Задача такова: Есть верстка,
> доступа к которой я не имею, но имею
> право вывести в body в самое начало
> элемент div высотой 100px. Чтобы все
> абсолютно позиционированные элементы
> не поехали, я по ним пробегусь и
> прибавлю +100px, а вот чтобы родной js
> верстки просчитывал верно мне
> нужно переопределить функцию top. Я
> ясно изъясняюсь?

UPD2: Представьте такую верстку:

```
<html>
<body>
[[HERE]]
<div style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;" id="div1">BLOCK</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:200px;">BLOCK</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.top='200px';">CLICK ME!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[[HERE]] - то самое место, где я размещаю div высотой 100px.
И вот что я должен сделать, чтобы событие onclick при нажатии на линк отрабатывалось не в 200px, а в 300px?

UPD3: Js может сделать, например вот так:

```
<html>
<body>
[[HERE]]
<div id="div1">BLOCK</div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:200px;">BLOCK</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.position='absolute';document.getElementById('div1').style.top='200px';">CLICK ME!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы чего сделать-то хотите? Получить значение CSS-свойства?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы по запросу из любого места страницы var a = document.getElementById(any_element).style.top, переменная "a" стала равна 1000px, при этом текущее реальное значение style.top элемента (как Вы говорите CSS-свойства) останется 20px и мне не нужно его возвращать! Другими словами мне нужно перегрузить обращение OBJECT.style.top!

Comment: >> "а вот чтобы родной js верстки не просчитывал неверно мне нужно переопределить функцию top"    - вот это поправьте.. не стыкуется..

Comment: Поправил. Ну суть понятна, что мне нужно?

Comment: Я никак не понимаю, почему обязательно переопределять style.top ? почему нельзя иначе? Или вы думаете, что изменив поведение top, вы как-то повлияете на работу самого браузера?

Comment: Ну я задачу расписал как мог. Я не вижу другого способа изменять положения элементов, которые могут динамически меняться js скриптами на странице.

Comment: По-моему, этот вариант решения проблемы — невероятно жёсткая жесть. Даже если это получится заставить работать хоть как-то, заставить это работать во всех браузерах — без шансов. Может попытаться изобрести что-нибудь с фреймами?

Comment: Кирилл отверг политкорректность :) По моему, пройтись по всем абсолютным дивам и пофиксить их позиции - и то меньшее злодейство, хотя и хак ещё тот.

Comment: Блин, ну понятно, что выжимка из задачи звучит так: «Прикрутить костыль к инвалиду». Идея в том, что, если решать эту задачу с помощью костыля, то в любом случае получится костыль в квадрате. Перекрытие css-стиля — это супер-костыль. Фреймы, конечно, зло, это не модно и не современно (а JS, наоборот, модно и современно), но с фреймами особенно париться не придётся.

Comment: Задача стоит так, что фреймы использовать нельзя, есть только 1 страница.

Comment: Тогда я бы швырнул заказчику в лицо деньги и сказал, что он идиот, раз такого хочет… Вам ведь потом это ещё и поддерживать придётся)))

Comment: Это мой проект :) Как раз тот, который у меня в профайле стоит :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм.

```
<div style="height: 100px; margin-bottom: -100px;"></div>
```

Не пойдет?
И почему в этот DIV не засунуть элемент [style] или как-то по-другому не обойти? Вы ведь скрипт можете вписать, значит, стили тоже должны быть доступны.

UPD:

```
function topPlus100(tagNames) {
  for (var tn in tagNames) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tagNames[tn]);
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
      if (els[i].style.position == 'absolute')
        els[i].style.top = (els[i].offsetTop+100)+'px';
    }
  }
```

Еще UPD: еще логичнее переписать родной JS верстки) Вообще очень бы посмотрел на верстку, где элементы спозиционированы относительно body с помощью JS =/

---

Ну раз уж я взялся))

```
<style type="text/css">.corrector { position: relative; margin-top: 100px; clear: both; }</style>
<style type="text/javacsript">
function topPlus100(tagNames) {
  for (var tn in tagNames) {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tagNames[tn]);
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
      if ((els[i].style.position == 'absolute') && (typeof(els[i].childNodes[0]) != 'undefined') && (els[i].childNodes[0].className!='corrector'))
        els[i].innerHTML = 
          '<div class="corrector"></div>'
          +els[i].innerHTML;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Могут быть неточности (писал тут), но суть должна быть понятна. Соответственно оптимизировать и можно на какое-нить событие или интервал на крайний случай вешать (если innerHTML тоже скриптами затрагивается).

---

Тогда читаем [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/108295/) , намекаю на top = (parseInt(_top)+100)+'px';

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Пример почему распишу в вопросе.

Comment: Дописал

Comment: Понимаете какая штука, я не имею доступа к верстке вообще никаким образом, всмысле я не знаю, что там будет, я могу сделать обход дом-дерева, но это ничего не даст, статику я затрону и все. Я могу добавить по элементу перед каждым абсолютным элементом, но это тоже не сработает, т.к. js, который на странице может, например сделать так, как я написал в UPD3.

Comment: Так для UPD3 вам и перегрузка не поможет. Там даже не +=, absolute && 200px означает, что объект в любом случае будет на 200px от верхнего края экрана. Допишу ссыль в вопрос, может, это как-то приспособите.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределять поведение базовых функций, таких как getElementById, **ОЧЕНЬ** плохая идея. Вы хотите добавить в **стили** что-то, что не является стилем. Это разрушение идеологии API. Это просто плохо. Это сбивает с толку и усложняет изучение кода другими людьми и вами же спустя какое-то время.

Если вам нужен top, то зачем городить всё это? Почему просто не получить *offsetTop* для найденного элемента? Или не сделать функцию для подсчёта абсолютной позиции с учётом всех вложенностей (таких реализаций через гугл можно найти море).

Comment: То, что это идея плохая - я вкурсе :) Но ничего не остается. Написал UPD.